# Prove that $\xi_{k+1} = (-1)^{k+1}(\alpha_0 \times \alpha_1 \times \dots \times \alpha_k)$ is the (k+1) coefficient of $p_k$

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization

I was given the following question as part of a homework assignment. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

> The following image shows the steps of a preliminary version of the conjugate gradient algorithm and was taken from the book *Numerical Optimization* by Jorge Nocedal and Stephen J. Wright.
>
> [image: Preliminary version of the conjugate gradient algorithm taken from the book Numerical Optimization by Jorge Nocedal and Stephen J. Wright]
>
> We know from a previous theorem that $p_{k+1} \in \text{span}\{r_0, A r_0, \dots, A^{k+1} r_0\}$, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is symmetric positive definite and $r_k \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$, therefore
> $$ p_{k+1} = \xi_0 r_0 + \xi_1 A r_0 + \dots + \xi_{k+1} A^{k+1} r_0 $$
> Show that $\xi_{k+1} = (-1)^{k+1}(\alpha_0 \times \alpha_1 \times \dots \times \alpha_k)$ using the preliminary version of the conjugate gradient method (Algorithm 5.1).

I have tried to solve this problem by Mathematical induction on $k$ since the base step is easy to prove, however, I haven't figured out a way to succesfully complete the induction step. I have tried using the following results:

1. $r_{k+1} = r_k + \alpha_{k} A r_{k}$
2. $r_k^T p_i = 0$ for $i = 0, 1, \dots, k-1$
3. $p_k^T A p_i = 0$ for $i = 0, 1, \dots, k-1$
4. $r_k^T r_i = 0$ for $i = 0, 1, \dots, k-1$

**Note**: the instructions never stated this, but I assumed that $\xi_0 = -1$ since it's essentially a definition in Algorithm 5.1.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to prove it (or at least something like it) using induction. Here's what we'll need:

1. $r_{k+1} = r_k + \alpha_k A p_k$. (deduced from Algorithm 5.1)
2. If $p_k \in \text{span}\{r_0, Ar_0, \dots, A^k r_0\}$, then $Ap_k \in \text{span}\{Ar_0, A^2 r_0, \dots, A^{k+1} r_0\}$.
3. $r_k \in \text{span}\{r_0, Ar_0, \dots, A^k r_0\}$.
4. By definition, $p_0 = -r_0$.

### Base Step

Let $k = 1$, then

$$p_k = p_1 = -r_1 + \beta_0 p_0 = -r_0 - \alpha_0 A p_0 + \beta_0 p_0$$

Since $p_0 = -r_0$, we get

$$p_1 = -r_0 + \alpha_0 A r_0 - \beta_0 r_0 = -(1 + \beta_0) r_0 + \alpha_0 Ar_0$$

Therefore, $p_k = p_1 \in \text{span}\{r_0, A r_0\} = \text{span}\{r_0, \dots, A^k r_0\}$.

### Inductive step

Let $k$ be a natural number. Our induction hypothesis is as follows:

$$\xi_k = (-1)^{k+1} (\alpha_0 \times \alpha_1 \times \dots \times \alpha_{k-1})$$

We now show that this equation holds for $k+1$.

$$p_{k+1} = -r_{k+1} + \beta_k p_k = -r_k - \alpha_k Ap_k + \beta_k p_k$$

therefore,

$$-\alpha_k A p_k = r_k - r_{k+1}$$

Since $r_k \in \text{span}\{r_0, Ar_0, \dots, A^k r_0\}$, we have

$$-\alpha_k A p_k = r_k - r_{k+1} = \sum_{i=0}^k \xi_i A^i r_0 - \sum_{i=0}^{k +1} \xi_i A^i r_0 = -\xi_{k+1} A^{k+1} r_0$$

Multiply by $A^{-1}$ from the left

$$\alpha_k p_k = \xi_{k+1} A^k r_0 \Rightarrow \alpha_k p_k - \xi_{k+1} A^k r_0 = 0$$

Now, dividing by $\alpha_k$ and substituting $p_k$ for its expression as a linear combination, we have

$$p_k - \frac{\xi_{k+1}}{\alpha_k} A^k r_0 = \sum_{i = 0}^k \xi_i A^i r_0 - \frac{\xi_{k+1}}{\alpha_k} A^k r_0 = \sum_{i = 0}^{k-1} \xi_i A^i r_0 + (\xi_k - \frac{\xi_{k+1}}{\alpha_k}) A^k r_0 = 0$$

$\{r_0, A r_0, \dots, A^k r_0\}$ are linearly independent, therefore every coefficient in the last equation must be equal to zero.

$$\xi_k - \frac{\xi_{k+1}}{\alpha_k} = 0 \Longleftrightarrow \xi_{k+1} = \alpha_k \xi_k = (-1)^2 \alpha_k \xi_k$$

and, using our inductive hypothesis, we get

$$\xi_{k+1} = (-1)^2 \alpha_k \xi_k = (-1)^2 \alpha_k \Big((-1)^k (\alpha_0 \times \alpha_1 \times \dots \times \alpha_{k-1}) \Big) = (-1)^{k+2} (\alpha_0 \times \alpha_1 \times \dots \times \alpha_{k-1} \times \alpha_k)$$

**Note:** I strongly suspect that the exponent associated to $-1$ in the original question is incorrect and the general form of the coefficients is actually $\xi_{k+1} = (-1)^{k+2} (\alpha_0 \times \alpha_1 \times \dots \times \alpha_{k-1} \times \alpha_k)$.